# Syntax for using UNNEST in node-postgres query-string to insert array as multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying it insert a simple array of numbers as different rows of a PostgreSQL table.

For example, I want to insert:

```
const arr = [1.1, 2.0, 3.40, 4.5, -5];
```

so that table 'numeric_values_list' populates to:

```
id | val 
--------
1  | 1.1
2  | 2.0
3  | 3.40
4  | 4.5
5  | -5.6
```

Using the psql terminal, I can get this query to produce the desired result:

```
INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val)
SELECT * FROM UNNEST (ARRAY[1.1, 2.0, 3.40, 4.5, -5]);
```

However, I cannot figure out the proper syntax for the postgres-pg query string that will produce the same result.  The following has not worked for me:

```
  const list = [1.1, 2.0, 3.40, 4.5, -5];

  // version 1
  db.query('INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1)', list)

  // version 2
  db.query('INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1::numeric[])', list)

  // version 3
  db.query('INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1::[])', list)

  // version 4
  db.query('INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) SELECT * FROM UNNEST ARRAY[($1)]', list)
```

My question is how do I get this to work using the pg-promise library?
Thanks much.

Comment: With [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) you could simply use [csv](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter) filter, and it would work ;)

Comment: oh, that is beautiful.  If you want to move your comment to an answer, I will check it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be much simpler when using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
const arr = [1.1, 2.0, 3.40, 4.5, -5];

db.none('INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[$1:csv])', [arr])
  .catch(error => {
      /* when in error */
  });
```

See [CSV Filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter).

And if your input is always a non-empty array, then it can be further simplified to just this:

```
db.none('INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1)', [arr])
  .catch(error => {
      /* when in error */
  });
```

That's because by default a non-empty array is formatted by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) as `array[...]`.

Check this out:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* init options */);

const s = pgp.as.format('$1', [arr]);

console.log(s); /*=> array[1.1,2,3.4,4.5,-5] */
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Using vitaly-t's suggestion, the following code does exactly what I wanted it to do:

```
const arr = [1.1, 2.0, 3.40, 4.5, -5];

...

db.query('                             \
  INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val) \
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[$1:csv])  \
', arr]);
```

---

ORIGINAL POST:

Not sure if this solution is ideal, but the following query produced the desired result:

```
const arr = [1.1, 2.0, 3.40, 4.5, -5];

const strList = String(arr);
const delimiter = ',';

...

db.query('                                                 \
  INSERT INTO numeric_values_list(val)                     \
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY($1, $2)::numeric[]) \
', [strList, delimiter]);
```